# Connect localhost Mysql from Docker .net core

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have working WebAPI in .net core in Docker. I want to deploy this API on AWS EC2 instance with local mysql database working with other web app.

How can I reach this Mysql from inside docker?

Locally I can do it by using my private ip addres in

```
=> optionsBuilder.UseMySql(@"Server=$my_local_ip;database=db_name;uid=user;pwd=pass;");
```

Ho to determine which `$my_local_ip` should I use in order to connect to DB?

But while using the private ip on EC2 I got error while sending request that it can't connect to any MYSQL host.

Comment: Is your MySQL database & the Web API container on the same machine? Is MySQL also running inside a container?

Comment: @JanshairKhan MySQL database and WebAPI are on the same machine. Only WebAPI is in the container. MySQL is working on localhost outside of the Docker.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL server you generally have to specify the port to connect to, as each instance on the same server uses a different port.

Comment: But this Mysql is not working inside docker. How docker would know where to look for this port?

Answer (score 1):

Use `--network=host` flag while starting the Web API container and use the `localhost` in you connection string as the host name. This will enable the Docker container to access the host network. Hence you can access MySQL Database from the container.

*Note: This is an insecure for running containerized workloads.* [Click Here to learn more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#default-networks)